# Enabling/Disabling a Form Button based on conditions

Tags: jquery

I am trying to disable a form button until some fields are filled, the button will be enable and clickable.

When i am filling all the required fields, the button remain disabled. When i am testing the if statement in the console after filling the fields, the button becomes enabled but not in the actual form!!

Shouldn't this if statement execute when the conditions are true when embedded in the form?

```
jQuery("#gform_next_button_2_81").css("cursor", "not-allowed");
jQuery("#gform_next_button_2_81").attr("disabled","disabled")


    if (jQuery.trim(jQuery("#input_2_2").val()) !=='' 
&& jQuery.trim(jQuery("#input_2_7").val()) !=='' 
&& jQuery.trim(jQuery("#input_2_298_1").val()) !=='' 
&& jQuery.trim(jQuery("#input_2_16_1").val()) !=='' 
&& jQuery.trim(jQuery("#input_2_17").val()) !=='' 
&& jQuery.trim(jQuery("#input_2_19").val()) !=='' 
&& jQuery.trim(jQuery("#input_2_22").val()) !=='' 
&& jQuery.trim(jQuery("#input_2_26_3").val()) !=='' 
&& jQuery.trim(jQuery("#input_2_28").val()) !==''
&& jQuery.trim(jQuery("#input_2_66").val()) !==''){

jQuery("#gform_next_button_2_81").css("cursor", "context-menu");     
jQuery("#gform_next_button_2_81").removeAttr("disabled")
}
```

Comment: Save yourself some grief and use the [`required` attribute](https://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/09-required.html)

Comment: These fields are already required, but the form is too long 8 Pages long and by disabling the button, we are telling the user the fields aren't all filled. I can't control the code of the form, it is auto-generated by a WP Gravity forms.

Comment: If the form is 8 pages long that means you have **8 separate webpages** which means you need **8 separate `<form>s** If you had one continuous scrolling page the size of 8 pages, you'd be OK.

Comment: Do you know how many `<form>` elements you have? `$('form').length`

Comment: Sorry, i am not explaining right. The form is too long it was 8 pages long but i put it inside accordion tabs. There is only 1 form and a "Next" Button. Your suggestion will be ideal if i could edit the code but i am obliged to work with what i have.

Comment: `$('input').attr('required', true);`

Comment: I have 1 `<form>` and more than 100 Fields

Comment: See updated answer, Demo 2 has 100 inputs on one form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163299/discussion-between-yma981-and-zer00ne).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have Added a Listener on the button. Now the button is enabling as it is supposed to.

```
 jQuery('#gform_next_button_2_81').mouseenter(function (){
if (jQuery.trim(jQuery("#input_2_2").val()) !=='' 
&& jQuery.trim(jQuery("#input_2_7").val()) !=='' 
&& jQuery.trim(jQuery("#input_2_298_1").val()) !=='' 
&& jQuery.trim(jQuery("#input_2_16_1").val()) !=='' 
&& jQuery.trim(jQuery("#input_2_17").val()) !=='' 
&& jQuery.trim(jQuery("#input_2_19").val()) !=='' 
&& jQuery.trim(jQuery("#input_2_22").val()) !=='' 
&& jQuery.trim(jQuery("#input_2_26_3").val()) !=='' 
&& jQuery.trim(jQuery("#input_2_28").val()) !=='' 
&& jQuery.trim(jQuery("#input_2_66").val()) !=='' ){

jQuery("#gform_next_button_2_81").css("cursor", "context-menu");     
jQuery("#gform_next_button_2_81").removeAttr("disabled")
}});
```